# Orientation in iOS 7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, orientation

If I push from rootViewController to detailViewController in landscape mode. My ScrollView is not changing the 'y' position. My code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"DetailViewController viewDidload - Start");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self delayedCheck];    
    NSLog(@"DetailViewController viewDidload - End");
}
-(void)delayedCheck {
    NSLog(@"delayedCheck start");

    UIInterfaceOrientation toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if (toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgL.jpg"]];
        [self.detailContentScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailContentScrollView.frame.origin.x, 170.0, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.width, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgP.jpg"]];
        [self.detailContentScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailContentScrollView.frame.origin.x, 185.0, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.width, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }

    NSLog(@"delayedCheck End");
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation");
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgL.jpg"]];
        [self.detailContentScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailContentScrollView.frame.origin.x, 170.0, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.width, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgP.jpg"]];
        [self.detailContentScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailContentScrollView.frame.origin.x, 185.0, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.width, self.detailContentScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the scrollview 'y' position in landscape mode. I navigate from rootViewController to detailViewController, In detailView - the position of scrollview is not changing.
Please help me out to change the position of 'y' origin of scrollView. Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Please reduce your code snippet to remove anything that is not relevant to your question and clear state what you are trying to achieve, and what your code currently does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 {
     UIInterfaceOrientation toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
     if (toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toStatusBarInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
     {
         self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgL.jpg"]];
     }
     else 
     {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgP.jpg"]];
     }
 }
```

I placed the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and made changes as mentioned in code.